# NodeJS async function doesn't run when inside of a while true loop

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, while-loop, async-await

Im trying to create a cookie generator by using puppeteer to capture cookies and add the cookies to a local json file. Everything works fine except when I'm trying to have the function run every 5 seconds it hangs and never completes the function. In python I used to do

```
while True:
   main()
   time.sleep(5)
```

But in node I'm doing this, and it hangs. Theres no errors it just hangs.

```
while (true){
   main()
}
```

my function never runs and it just hangs. Heres the `main` function simplified.

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
}

main = async () => {
    let start = now();

    puppeteer.launch( {headless:true} ).then( async (browser) => {
        console.log('Loaded Browser Successfully!')
        const page = await browser.newPage()
        await page.goto('some link')
        const cookies = await page.cookies();

        await sleep(5000)
        for(let cookie of cookies){
            if (cookie.name == 'some cookie')
                console.log(cookie)
        }
        await browser.close()
        return cookies
    }).then( async (cookies) => {
        let rawData = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'Cookies.json'))
        let cookieJar = JSON.parse(rawData)
        cookieJar.push(cookies)
        console.log(cookieJar.length)
        await fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'Cookies.json'), JSON.stringify(cookieJar))

        let end = now();
        console.log(`It took ${end - start}ms`)
        return
    })
    
}
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Nothing main does has any interaction on whether or not the while loop continues. Therefore, irregardless of whether or not main has finished what it needs to do, the while loop continues until it is hard stopped.

Comment: As a kind tip: Your code suggests, that you've not fully understood the basics of asynchronicity in JS. Additionaly, you'd usually not mix usage of `await` and `then(...)` (generally you should almost always use `await` when you can). MDN is a good place to learn the basics on JS' [concurrency model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop), [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) and [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS never runs code *in parallel*, only asynchronously. Your asynchronous `Promise`-callback can only ever run, *after* your current execution finishes. Since you used a `while (true)`, it will never finish.

For your problem, [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) is ideal:

```
setInterval(main, 5000)
```

Comment: this works, but now my ```await fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'Cookies.json'), JSON.stringify(cookieJar))``` doesn't work, it restarts the function while not waiting for my file to be updated, how could I fix this?

Comment: Since you're using `writeFileSync` (the _sync_ version) you wouldn't need to `await` it in the first place. But generally, if you only want to re-trigger the action _5 seconds after it finished_, instead of _every 5 seconds_, then you would be better served with calling `setTimeout(main, 5000)` at the very end of your procedure (that is, somewhere around your `console.log`), instead of using `setInterval`.

Comment: ```await fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'Cookies.json'), JSON.stringify(cookieJar))

        let end = now();
        console.log(`It took ${end - start}ms`)
    })
    setTimeout(main, 10000)
}
setTimeout(main, 10000)
```
This works perfect thank you

Comment: Alright, but please also note my comment on the question. I now see two `setTimeout(main, 10000)`s in your comment. If done wrong, this could either lead to two independent timers regularly retriggering the action (thus triggering the action twice every 10 seconds), or - even worse - a regular duplication of of timers leading to an ever-increasing amount of `setTimeout`-calls piling up your event queue and somewhat paralyzing your application.